# Get list like CNN-app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm curious how to get a (visual) list like in the CNN-app

[image: Example]

How to get multiple lines per item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i guess right you are searching for ListBox control. [Here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Listbox_handling_in_Windows_Phone) and [Here](http://3water.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/listbox-on-wp7/) are good examples that may be solve your problem..

Comment: Use a LongListSelector in preference of a ListBox for better performance and more display options.